# $\mathbb E[Xf(X)] = \gamma \mathbb E[f(X+1)]$ for every $f: \mathbb Z^{\ge 0} \to \mathbb R \implies X$ has distribution $Po(\gamma)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-explanation, poisson-distribution

If $f:= \mathbb 1_{k}$ for $k \in \mathbb Z^{>0}$, then $$k\mathbb P(X=k) = \gamma \mathbb P(X = k-1).$$

I used Characteristic Root Technique by letting $\mathbb P(X=k) = t^k$, but I do not think this can solve the problem.

How to show that $\mathbb P(X=k) = \frac{\gamma^k}{k!} e^{-\gamma}$?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand as currently written. What is $X$ (a random variable?) and $f$ (it's density?), how is $f$ used here, and what is "Characteristic Root Technique"?

Comment: @WillM. I take the question to mean $X$ is a random variable taking values in the set  $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ of finite cardinal numbers and $f$ is any function for which the expected values are defined. The "Robbins lemma" (named after Herbert Robbins) says that if $X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda),$ then for any such function, the stated identity holds. The identity is used in actuarial mathematics. That is what Robbins was thinking about in the 1950s when he introduced it.

Comment: The conspicuous typographical difference between $\gamma\mathbb E(X)$ and $\gamma\operatorname{\mathbb E}(X)$ is the first thing one is aware of when looking at this question. `\operatorname{}` gives you context-dependent horizontal spacing.

Comment: @WillM. : So this question is about a proposed converse to the Robbins lemma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $c=P(X=0)$. From the expression you wrote, you can infer by induction that
$$P(X=k)=c\gamma^k/k! $$
for all integers $k \ge 0$. To find the value of $c$, sum this equation over all $k \ge 0$ and recall the Taylor series for $e^\gamma$.